# Stripe with node.js + express checkout issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe into my checkout, and I am getting a small error that I cant seem to fix.  When clicking on the checkout button, instead of getting the checkout page, I instead get shown the following:
{"url":"https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_rest_of_link_here"}
So somehow, I am not getting directed as I should.  Here is the code I have so far:

**customer_cart controllers file**

```
const AllProduct = require('../database_models/allproduct');
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)
module.exports.checkout = async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.cart) {
        req.flash('error', 'There are no items to be checked out');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    try {
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            mode: 'payment',
            line_items: req.session.cart.map(item => {
                return {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: 'gbp',
                        product_data: {
                            name: item.productName
                        },
                        unit_amount: item.itemPrice
                    },
                    quantity: item.quantity * 100
                }
            }),
            success_url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/success`,
            cancel_url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/cancel.html`
        })
        res.json({ url: session.url })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
    }
};
```

**customer routes file**

```
// Require Modules
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const cart = require('../controllers/customer_cart');

const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const ExpressError = require('../utils/ExpressError');

const { productSchema } = require('../joivalidations.js');
const { isLoggedIn } = require('../middleware');

const AllProduct = require('../database_models/allproduct');

router.get('/add/:id', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(cart.addToCart));

router.get('/', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(cart.viewCart));

router.get('/clear', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(cart.clearCart));


router.get('/checkout', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(cart.checkout))
router.post('/checkout', isLoggedIn, catchAsync(cart.checkout));

module.exports = router;
```

**And the checkout.ejs file**

```
<% layout('layouts/productboilerplate')%>

    <h1>TEST</h1>

    <!-- Display a payment form -->
    <button>Checkout</button>

    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector("button")
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            fetch('/cart/checkout', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    items: req.session.cart,
                }),
            }).then(res => {
                if (res.ok) return res.json()
                return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
            }).then(({ url }) => {
                console.log(url)
                window.location.href = url
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            })
        })
    </script>
```

I suspect I am not handling the url property properly in the checkout.ejs file, but would appreciate some opinions as I have been starting at this to long now and not getting anywhere fast

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally looks alright. You're responding with that JSON data here:
`res.json({ url: session.url })`

So you should trace through your `fetch().then()...` chain to see where things go awry.

Are you getting `res.ok`? Are you seeing the `console.log(url)` output? Go one step at a time and make sure you're getting the expected result at each stage.